# 2d packing shapes in rooms

Tags: 2d, grid

I'm not sure of the correct terms for this so having a hard time searching.

But I have a series of 2d top-down rooms made up of random grid sizes between say 5 and 10 on the x and y axis. Each room will have one or more doors.

Now I want to place furniture shapes in them randomly, with some rules like not blocking a door, overlapping other furniture etc. For example a sofa would be 3x1 size, a tv unit 2x1 etc, but can be rotated.

What are my options for doing this? I can think of two methods:

1. Brute forcing it, looping each item until it fits somewhere.
2. Similar to the Spelunky method, whereby I make various room layouts and randomly pick one.

Comment: It sounds like you have two workable strategies for how to implement this feature. Have you encountered a problem with one strategy or the other that we can help you overcome, or an aspect of these solutions you're unsatisfied with that we can focus on alternatives to improve?

Comment: Both should work but your second approach will give you a better looking result and is going to be easier to implement in the way that it will give nice looks. In first method you would need to take rotation into account (TV facing the wall) or grouping of elements (the sofa is dividing the table from the chairs) or a room has 3 lamps but nothing else.